# Stationary point in de Sitter-Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, cosmological-constant

In de Sitter-Schwarzschild spacetime things close to the black hole are falling towards it whereas in greater distance they are receding. So there should be a certain (unstable) $r$-coordinate, where things are stationary. The de Sitter-Schwarzschild metric yields 2 solutions:

$f(r)=1-2M/r$

$f(r)=1-\Lambda*r^2$

From this the stationary $r$-coordinate should be $r=(2M/\Lambda)^{1/3}$.

But is this correct? Please advise.